Old SSIS Package can't read XLSX file - XLS reads fine
I was asked to take a look into why an SSIS package that is running through SQL Server 2012 isn't working properly. I opened the package and saw that the error is due to an inability to read the .xlsx file.
As a test, I opened the file manually, saved it as an .xls file, and changed the connector to read it as a 97-2003 excel file - and it worked fine. I resaved that .xls as an .xlsx (thinking maybe the original was just broken) and the 2007 connection fails again.
Looking at the error logs, I see one error that is:

Hresult: 0x800004005 Description: "Could not find installable ISAM"

Searching around I'm not finding much luck. Does anyone know what the problem here is? I validated that the permissions on the file are correct, it is not locked by another process, the path is correct. Not sure what else I can do. I'm guessing it's related to this archaic server that is running this with SQL Server 2012.
Connection string is: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\<my server>\shared\<the folder>\<filename>.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=NO";

The error is related to the Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; You need to check if the Microsoft ACE Provider 12.0 is installed. You can check it in the SSMS: EXEC master.sys.sp_enum_oledb_providers; It will show all 64-bit OLEDB providers installed on the server.

Thanks for the suggestion, this led me to finding that the OLEDB driver installed was corrupted. Thanks!

The solution was that the ACE redistributable was either damaged or corrupted. I couldn't even uninstall it, I had to repair it through the add/remove programs, then uninstall it, then download the latest 32 bit version and install, and that fixed it. The installed version also didn't seem to match the microsoft version either.
I downloaded Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920
Version:
RTM
Date Published:
8/11/2020
Installed the 32 bit version.
